# Is it possible to develop pure HTML5 applications with PhoneGap?

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, html, cordova

Even after searching PhoneGap's website and their support group, I still cannot find an answer to my question:

Currently, I'm planning on developing an application that should exists as a pure HTML5 application, being able to run in any modern browser (Google Chrome, Safari, etc.) as well as on Android/iPad as native mobile applications.

So **my question is:**

Is it possible to use the same code base to develop both pure HTML5 applications as well as native mobile applications with PhoneGap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhoneGap is in effect a runtime environment for HTML, javascript, and any CSS that may accompany your code. So in short:

> Yes, but it is recommended that you have some knowledge of Objective-C if you want to develop any iPhone app with extended functionality. If you have the right dimensions/proportions for the code there is no reason why you cannot simply copy that code into PhoneGap and compile it.

Answer (score 3):

See, the support for #HTML5 varies from browser to browser, and varies a lot from a desktop browser to mobile browser. If one has to convert web-portal to a mobile application that can easily be done through Phonegap, you can refer to this link also. https://build.phonegap.com/ It worked fine for me.

Now lets come to Phonegap, what phonegap does is it has created wrapper through javascript that calls the native apis. Now to show content they use WebView object which renders your html5 page in your app. And you can create your own wrappers too. Not that much difficult.

So if your app is only a web based portal, that does not need much native access, you can easily reuse one codebase make #cross-platform apps using Phonegap. Else you need to go for hybrid apps.